# Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client although I have command line svn

Tags: svnant

I'm trying to use svnant. Here's my xml:

```
<!-- SVN settings -->
<target name="init.svn">
    <path id="svnant.classpath">
        <fileset dir=".../svnant">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
    <svnSetting svnkit="false" javahl="false" id="svn.settings"/>
</target>

<target name="checkouttag" depends="init.svn">
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <checkout url="${svn.tags}/${TAG_NAME}" destpath="${TAG_NAME}" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

I expect command line svn to be used but I'm getting "Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client" error although I do can run svn from command line.
I'm using ant-1.8.4 and svn-1.6.4. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I could do nothing with this and decided not to use svnant at all. Just directly call svn command line from ant instead.